# Why some queries hang while others work

Tags: redshift

We have our redshift cluster due to some strange reasons it started to be slow. And in the same time if I just query something very simple it will give me results for some tables and will never return for others. Any idea whats happening ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with Java code. The code was opening connection and starting transactions. But when ever some exception happen in the middle of the code, i was not closing the transaction. So the until the current open transactions are done the tables are locked, and any one else do not get chance to access them